# SSIS - Dynamically get connection manager name

Tags: ssis

I set up a flat file connection, and want to dynamically get the connection manager name so that I can use that name in the expression builder.In the image as an example, I set the name to "Address.csv"

[image]

I want to dynamically grab the connection manager name and add it here where I circled. Is that possible?

[image]

I tried to look in the Variablesa and Parameters drop down but nothing that gives me the "connection manager name". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the Name of the connection manager is not a property you can work with as you're demonstrating.

You can set the Name of a Connection Manager dynamically but that's the inverse of what it seems you would like to accomplish.

[image]

I suppose you could try a Script Task to get the value of a Connection manager. Create a Variable of type string. I am going to use a variable named FFCM_via_Task (Flat File Connection Manager via Task) and add it to the read/write collection of the scrip task.

The following snippet of C# will enumerate through all the connections in the package and assign the value to our variable (as well as pop it onto the Information event which gets logged by default)

```
    public void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = false;
        // TODO: What should happen if there are multiple connections?
        // How do you know what "address.csv" is called without knowing the "name"
        foreach (var item in Dts.Connections)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Demo", item.Name, "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            Dts.Variables["User::FFCM_via_Task"].Value = item.Name;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

After the script task has executed, we can see the name is listed at address.csv

What I can't address is your TODO in the code. How would the Script Task "know" what the correct connection manager it should be using as "name."

[image]

Finally, as a practitioner of SSIS for just shy of 20 years, I've never had a cause to go at a connection manager name like you're attempting. It might be that you've stumbled into a corner case I've never thought of or you might be going about it (dynamicism) in a...circuitous route.

### Update based on the comment

Rather than derive the file name dynamically, just hard code it.

Thus, your problem can be simplified to an expression like this

> @[User::DynamicPath] + "Address.csv"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have multiple connections to flat files and I dont think this would work. For my situation, I have about 102 flat files that I get each morning, where the name of the flat file always remains the same (i.e. the Address.csv file I got today will be names Address.csv tomorrow). The path/folder changes though. Each day, I create a folder based on todays date (folder_20240126) and download today's CSV files into that folder. I was hoping that I could use a package parameter to specify the path of where today's data is held, then get the flat file based on "connection manager name"

Comment: So to restate the problem, you need a way to specify for each Flat File Connection Manager, a dynamic folder but constant file name?

Comment: I hear... go download a file and place it here and then process it here and think of all the wasted effort. Just use web client and process the stream. You can save the stream to a file system or database for archives if you want to. Personally, I would use .NET, spend some time on making a forever solution and never think about this problem ever again.